# Почему pylint выдает это сообщение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, side_a=1, side_b=1):
        self.side_a = side_a
        self.side_b = side_b
    def get_area(self):
        return self.side_a * self.side_b
square = Rectangle(2, 2)
print(square.get_area())
```

Pylint выдает сообщение "*Invalid constant name "square" (invalid-name)*"

Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот более подробный вывод *Pylint* для данного кода:

```
C:  7,0: Invalid name "square" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
```

Поскольку конструктор класса `Rectangle` вызывается с конкретными числовыми параметрами, а переменная `square` больше нигде не изменяется, то анализатор предполагает, что `square` является константой. Общее правило состоит в том, что имена констант пишутся БОЛЬШИМИ БУКВАМИ, т.е. *Pylint* хочет видеть на этом месте имя `SQUARE`.